# Combination of possible values in an array with multiple constraints in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, constraints, combinations

I have an array B of :

```
B=[1 2 3; 10 20 30 ; 100 200 300 ; 1000 2000 3000]
```

such that

```
B =

           1           2           3
          10          20          30
         100         200         300
        1000        2000        3000
```

I am using the following code to find the possible combination between these variables that are below a certain value (a constraint) -- 2000 in this case :

```
A=[123; 323; 12 ; 421]
SA=sum(A)
V=cell(length(B),1);
n=1;
for k = 1:length(B)
    for idx = nchoosek(1:length(B), k)'
        B_subset = B(idx);
        if (SA + sum(B_subset) <= 2000)
            V(n)={B_subset(:)}; %store them in a cell
            n=n+1;
        end
    end
end
```

However I failed to combine them the way I want below.

---

Objective :

Find the possible combinations from B to be added with SA so that their sum is less than 2000 ?

---

Constraint 1 :

- Only one value from each row in array `B` can be used at once.

For example, this is **NOT** acceptable : [1 2 20] [2 20 30]
This is the **correct** one : [1 20 100] [3 200 3000]

---

Constraint 2 :
 - The answers should be stored in the cell V in only one column (as initialised in the code above).

The cell should have an output similar to the one I'm currently having :

```
V = 

    [       100]
    [       300]
    [       200]
    [2x1 double]
    [2x1 double]
    [2x1 double]
    [3x1 double]
```

Comment: are the contents of `V` OK? Do you just need output formatting?

Comment: I'll update question with how V should look

Comment: The `V` looks suspiciously familiar :) Will update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your code just a bit and added a test below - if V is unchanged -> there were no combinations -> display that. Edited to allow saving it into cell array `V` and simultaneously constructing a string for printing.

This code considers every combination of three elements from B, where each element is from a different column.

```
V=cell(length(B),1);
A=[123; 323; 12 ; 421];
SA=sum(A);
S = 'possible combinations :';
n = 1
for ii=1:4
    for jj=1:4
        if jj == ii
            continue
        end
        for kk=1:4
            if or(kk == jj,kk == ii)
                continue
            end
            B_subset = [B(ii,1), B(jj,2), B(kk,3)];
            if (SA + sum(B_subset) <= 2000)
                S = [S, ' ', mat2str(B_subset)];
                V{n} = B_subset;
                n += 1;
            end
        end
    end
end

if V == 'possible combinations :'
    disp('No possible combinations found')
else
    disp(S)
end
```

EDIT: adding answer to the new part of the question. In the inner-most loop the different combinations of included rows are calculated.

```
V = {}
for ii=1:3
    for jj=1:3
        for kk=1:3
            for ll = 1:3
                rows = [ii, jj, kk, ll]
                if isequal(rows, unique(rows))
                    % loop for turning off individual elements
                    result = [B(1,ii), B(2,jj), B(3,kk), B(4,ll)]
                    for mm = 0:1:15
                        % make a binary string - will loop through all combinations of zeros and ones
                        str1 = dec2bin(mm,4)
                        mask = zeros(1,4)
                        for nn = 1:4 % make a numeric vector
                            mask(nn) = str2num(str1(nn))
                        end
                        masked_result = mask.*result
                        V = [V {masked_result}]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The code still uses values from the same row, such as `100   200  30` or `10   200    30`

Comment: You said one value from each column: this is done with the three loops. Then you said only one value per row - which is done with continues. It can't do `100 200 30` because `jj` and `ii` would be the same and it would continue before checking for answer. `V` has old values in it, because it wasn't initialized again. I've updated the answer, also changing looping to 4 for the whole B.

Comment: @NLed: I don't understand what you want. Every viable answer is a 1x3 matrix. Why are there 4 elements? Also, do you want to also print answers that exceed 2000 or even combinations that share a row or column?

Comment: Hm. I think I know what you want, but this is a large number of results - seems like over 60. Don't quite know how to do it. Still thinking :)

Comment: @NLed: the end for the last `for` was missing. I fixed the answer. Python doesn't have `end`s.

Comment: The code runs, but only updates rows from rows= 1 1 1 1 to rows= 3 3 3 3  .. `V={ [] [] [] [] }` no values updated

Comment: Btw, if length of B changes to more than 4, I have to add an extra for loop right ?? Wouldnt EitanT's code be more efficient regarding this issue ? Maybe adding your edit and integrating it with EitanT's code provide a more robust code ? Maybe also providing a simpler means to debug the code rather than having more than 3 for loops ?

Comment: Look man, I gave it my best. Your request are strange and hard to comprehend. Plus I don't think this question is going to help anyone else - so we are littering here. Please try to do something by yourself and especially try to understand what the code does. Matlab has an excellent framework for running scripts and checking values after each line of code. I really suggest you try it. You can run scripts right from Matlab's text editor.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, not saying otherwise. Sorry if it seemed I'm implying anything.

Comment: You're right, adding that extra part made the question incomprehensible. I will remove it from this question.

Comment: My main point is: please start learning things by experimenting with Matlab. Create a new file in Matlab's editor, paste the code inside, save it, and click on the step-by-step run button. You'll be able to execute one line at a time and also check variables at each line. That way it will be easier to see what went wrong.

Comment: I am really trying, trust me, I am :) I am currently still trying to do this using EitanT's code. If nothing worked im going to ask it as a separate question. I always ask for explanations rather than copy/paste a code because I want to learn. This task is too complex for my level of matlab knowledge, but I am still trying :)

Comment: I have opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284999/how-to-structure-a-cell-to-store-values-in-a-specific-format-in-matlab .. trust me I have been trying to work on that guy's answer for ages .. 4.30am now and still trying to debug the code ( as you advised me to ). I really am trying. Please check the question and see if you can provide any help if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, this fix should do the trick:

```
SA = sum(A);
V = cell(numel(B), 1);                  % // Changed 'length' to 'numel'
n = 1;
for k = 1:size(B, 1)                    % // Changed 'length' to 'size'
    for idx = nchoosek(1:numel(B), k)'  %'// Changed 'length' to 'numel'

        %// Ignore the combination if there are two elements from the same row
        rows = mod(idx, size(B, 1));
        if ~isequal(rows, unique(rows))
            continue
        end

        B_subset = B(idx);
        if (SA + sum(B_subset) <= 2000)
            V(n) = {B_subset(:)};
            n = n + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Perhaps it's not the most efficient solution there is, but it's short and it works.

Comment: example, what does ~isequal mean ? and how is this code going over different rows/columns before checking if they are viable combinations ?

Comment: @NLed `numel` means number of elements - in this case it is 4x3=12. `~` is negation in matlab, so this `~isequal` means if `rows` is not equal to `unique(rows)` - that happens when there are duplicated elements in `rows`

Comment: @EitanT I have used your code for another question, maybe it will interest you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284999/how-to-structure-a-cell-to-store-values-in-a-specific-format-in-matlab

Comment: @NLed Did this code resolve the problem described in this question?

Comment: @EitanT Yes I am actually using your code now with just minor tweaks, which I really appreciate very much. If you are interested to see how it looks like then let me know.